# ¿Cómo crear un archivo txt en Java?

Tags: java

Mi código:

```
javax.swing.JFileChooser jF1 = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();


     String ruta = "home/luis/Documentos";
     try{
         if(jF1.showSaveDialog(null)== jF1.APPROVE_OPTION){

             ruta= jF1.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            //Aqui creas el archivo 
         }
     }
         catch(Exception ex){

                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

Este bloque de código sólo abre el explorador de archivos pero no crea nada. 
Pregunta: **¿Cómo puedo crear un archivo?**

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado sobre creación de archivos en Java? El bloque que colocas sólo abre una ventana de diálogo y muestra carpetas en el directorio Documentos, pero no te creará un archivo. Edita tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen diferentes clases que deberías conocer: File, BufferedWriter y FileWriter.

- *File*: Se usará para comprobar si existe el fichero especificado.
- *FileWriter*: Se usará para especificar el archivo en el que se va a escribir.
- *BufferedWriter*: se encargará de escribir en el archivo.

Lo primero, comprobamos si existe el fichero:

```
String ruta = "home/luis/Documentos";
File archivo = new File(ruta);
BufferedWriter bw;
if(archivo.exists()) {
      // El fichero ya existe
} else {
      // El fichero no existe y hay que crearlo
      bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
      bw.close(); // Debe cerrarse la escritura del fichero
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando java puedes crear un archivo usando el método `createNewFile()` de la clase `File`:

```
String ruta = "home/luis/Documentos/archivo.txt";

File file = new File(ruta);

if(!file.exists())
{
   file.createNewFile();
}
```